# What's the difference between WriteObject(x, true) and multiple writeobjects when writing a PowerShell cmdlet?

Tags: powershell, powershell-cmdlet

I want to write a cmdlet that reads multiple records from a database and puts them onto the pipeline.

I think I can do either a single `WriteObject(Enumerable<rec>, true)` or I can loop myself and call `WriteObject` multiple times.

What's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the documentation: [Cmdlet.WriteObject Method (Object, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

And here is the example:

```
# Writes objects one by one
function Test1
{
    [CmdletBinding()]param()
    $data | %{ $PSCmdlet.WriteObject($_) }
}

# Writes the collection and allows the core to enumerate it one level.
# Numbers of written objects is the collection item count.
function Test2
{
    [CmdletBinding()]param()
    $PSCmdlet.WriteObject($data, $true)
}

# Writes the collection as a single object.
# Numbers of written objects is 1.
function Test3
{
    [CmdletBinding()]param()
    $PSCmdlet.WriteObject($data, $false)
}

function Test
{
    (Test1).GetType().Name
    (Test2).GetType().Name
    (Test3).GetType().Name
}

$data = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

Write-Host "1 item"
$null = $data.Add('hello')
Test

Write-Host "2+ items"
$null = $data.Add('world')
Test
```

Output:

```
1 item
String
String
ArrayList
2+ items
Object[]
Object[]
ArrayList
```

Thus, calling `WriteObject(item)` for each item in a collection is basically the same as `WriteObject(items, true)`; in both cases the collection itself has gone.

`WriteObject(items, false)` is different; it returns a reference to the collection and the caller can use that effectively depending on a scenario. For example, if a collection is a `DataTable` object (not unrolled set of `DataRow` items) then a caller can operate on `DataTable` members of the returned object.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `WriteObject(Object, boolean)` will allow you to output a collection and have it stay intact (if called with "false" for the second argument).  Normally PowerShell will enumerate any collections that get put on the pipeline.

So you could output a string array and the result would be of type [String[]].  While if you let PowerShell unwrap it, it will be an array of strings in a [Object[]].

You can also call that overload with "true" and it will be just like a loop calling `WriteObject(Object)`.