# How do I return a value or object from a C# PowerShell command to PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-module

I am using a C# library (.NET 4) with the System.Management.Automation DLL file to implement some commands for PowerShell (2.0).

I need to get a value from a command in a PowerShell script.

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Get, "MyCommand")]
public class GetMyCommand : Cmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        // How do I return a value to PowerShell?
    }
}
```

The way I would like to get a value is something like this:

```
$value = Get-MyCommand
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the [CmdLet.WriteObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.writeobject%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.

[Here is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6394004/520612) a good explanation from @RomanKuzmin.